# how to edit bootstrap css files in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

hello I am working in Laravel 5.2 app and bootstrap.My bootstrap file is in public folder of the Laravel app. now I need change color of following div tag of "Welcome"

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    Your Application's Landing Page.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then how can I change color of this? may I access bootstrap css files in public folder?

Comment: Never edit the official css files or js libraries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you may, to keep it simple you should link a stylesheet in welcome.blade.php file like so:

```
<link type="stylesheet" css="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" />
```

(this will look for a css file in /public/css/stlye.css)

in stlye.css file add the following css:

```
.panel-heading {
   background-color: green; /* will change the background color */
   color: blue; /* will change the color of the font */
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is "really" how you should do it in the general case. What you should do is modify the core code, and re-compile your assets so that the style.css file is regenerated (and minimised) in your public directory. Your manual update way will work for a rudimentary case such as this, but it's not a scalable solution.

Answer (score 2):

What I do (without being tooooo experienced in Laravel) is add a css file of my own in public/css with the styles I want to change, then include this in app.blade.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" />
```

The easiest way would then be to add an id attribute to your welcome line:

```
<div id="my-welcome" class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>
```

and then add a style like this to your style.css:

```
#my-welcome {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd use a class, `<div class="welcome panel-heading">`, to keep the specificity low. Otherwise, this is spot on, create a selector with equal or higher specificity than the original and include after original selector to override.